# What preposition should be used with "strong"?

Tags: prepositions

For instance, is there difference in the following phrases:?

> An engineer must be strong of Mathematical Skills.

and

> An engineer must be strong in Mathematical Skills.

Comment: I think this is a sentence fragment. I'd say: **An** engineer must have strong mathematical skills. (No capitals are necessary, imo.)

Comment: @Willow, of course! This is the main problem for english learners, whose native language doesn't suppose (undefinite) arcticles at all :-))

Comment: I am not a grammar guru, so further explanations must come from one of them -- there are quite a few here. I am finding that the English-learners often have a better grasp of grammar than I do.

Comment: **strong in** is much more idiomatic than *strong of*.  (By the way, it's math**e**matical.)

Comment: @stangdon thx! Is there anymore prepositions that are used with _strong_? And also as an offtopic - is this really confusing so much when someone says something without undefinite article (Engineer must be smart)?

Comment: @jumpjet67 Confusingly, you _can_ use **of** with **strong**, it's just that you wouldn't with _mathematical skills_. E.g. "He was **strong of mind**", meaning "he was strong-minded". I don't know what the Rules are (if there are any) though.

Comment: I agree with @SteveES - I think when we're talking about skills or knowledge, it's "strong **in**", but when talking about personal characteristics, it's "strong **of**".

Answer (score 1):

Use *in* or *with*, preferably *in*:

> An engineer must be strong in Mathematical Skills.

*Of* can be used but it sounds literary and/or dramatic, or like you are trying to say something near a common set of words "Strong of body, mind, soul."